# Automate PayPal commission payments from Merchant when someone subscribes

Tags: php, api, paypal

I'm building a site for a client that involves a number of content creator users that other users can subscribe to with automatically recurring monthly payments (think OnlyFans). All transactions are to go through PayPal, which I thought would be the easiest solution. I'm coding in PHP (WordPress environment) using Curl to call the REST API.

I've got the content creators on-boarding fine as merchants. I originally went down the path of creating Orders, and PayPal has a great commission tool in that system so that my client will get their commission every time a user starts a subscription. I was going to take care of the recurring payments at my own end, but then I discovered PayPal's Subscription system - it seemed perfect, but it doesn't have the automatic commission facility of the orders system, which is a bummer. So I could have PayPal automate the commissions while I programmed a subscription system, or I could use their subscription system and ... what?

That's where I'm stuck. I now need to automate PayPal deducting a payment from my merchant and paying it to my client as their commission. This needs to be done whenever a subscription is started and then each month as the subscription payment comes through. I've tapped into web-hooks to get notified when these automated monthly payments are happening (at least I'm hoping I have), but how can I automate a percentage of the initial payment and each subsequent monthly payment to be automatically deducted from the merchant and paid to my client?

I've looked at orders, but that needs to be approved by the merchant. What else is available to me?

Comment: Hi Craig. Change the hyphenation of "on-boarding" and "web-hooks" if you wish, but the [brand name is camel-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PayPal).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: What halfer said -- [editing is perfectly fine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), and also encouraged. Craig, please refrain from further rollbacks when the post unlocks. The edit is fine

Answer (score 1):

To automate sending payments from your own account to creators or affiliates, you could potentially use Payouts.

See [here for information on requesting access to Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to send money from a creator's account (partner merchant) to my client's account, which I can't seem to do without the creator having to manually approve it. But your suggestion has given me an idea I might try out.

Comment: If wish to automate billing in the other direction, then you need the 'reference transactions' feature to be approved for the account doing the billing. Reference transactions allows the use of billing agreements or vaulting, for the creation of future arbitrary transactions.

Comment: Thanks for that. As I read the documentation for Reference transactions, they initiate another transaction on the card of the original purchaser. ie, user purchases a subscription from one of our creators, then that first user is charged a second time for the site's commission fee. Again, not the solution I was looking for. Please let me know if I've misunderstood that. 

I want the original user to purchase their subscription from one of our creators, then I want to charge the creator a percentage of that subscription fee and deposit that amount into the site's PayPal account.